# Can't parse JSON data structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, django, json

How do pass back values to a form that was posted to the server using Ajax?

In the view (shown below), I am just returning a simple data structure to test things:

```
def detail(request, widget_id):

    widget = get_object_or_404(Widget, pk=widget_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WidgetDetailsForm(request.POST, instance=widget)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)  # Redirect after POST
        else:
            if request.is_ajax():
                response_dict = {
                    'page': 1,
                    'total': 2,
                    'rows': 3
                }
                json = simplejson.dumps(response_dict)
                return HttpResponse( json, mimetype='application/json')

    else:
        form = WidgetDetailsForm(instance=widget)

    params = {}
    params['widget'] = widget
    params['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('widgets/detail.html', params,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The JavaScript in the template is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        // Wait for the DOM to be loaded
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function.
            $('#updateform').wl_Form({
                onSuccess: function(data, status){
                    alert(data);
                    alert(data.page);
                    alert(data.rows);
                    alert(data.total);
                },
                "status": false,
                "confirmSend": false
            });
        });
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

I get the following from the alert statements.

```
{"rows": 3, "total": 2, "page": 1}
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Why does `data.page`, `data.rows`, and `data.total` return undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `data` is a string (of JSON) - note the output of your first `alert()`.

Try something like:

```
$('#updateform').wl_Form({ 
    onSuccess: function(response, status){
        var data = $.parseJSON(response); 
        alert(data);
        alert(data.page);
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly. You passed the data back fine. But only bytes (in this case, interpreted as a string, which represents something in JSON format) can be transmitted over the internet. On the receiving end, you need to interpret this result. I'm confused because your question says "Can't parse...", but the code doesn't actually make any **attempt** to parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

and dont forget do include `json2.js` for older browsers?

It depends on what `wl_Form` does.